# Change the font colour of validation error message in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How can we change the font colour of validation error messages in Yii2?

This is my form with the price empty after I pressed the create button and therefore it has triggered the validation message 'cannot be blank'. But I want the message to be easily discernible by the user. Currently the validation works perfectly but the user will battle to see where they have made a mistake particularly on a large form. As you can see there is no bootstrap colour eg. 'warning' associated with the message. The message does not stand out.

I am preferably looking for a global setting either in css or in the Assetmanager that I can adjust so that I do not have to adjust each and every required 'message' under the rules section for each model's attribute.

I am running:

yii2 2.0.35 on wampserver
php 7.4.4

This is my code under my model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['listprice'], 'required'],
```

[This is my composer.json](https://github.com/rossaddison/yii2-house2house/blob/cleaning/composer.json)

Please can someone help? I want all error messages to be red preferably.

[image]

Thank you Bizley for your reply. Ok this is my DOM.

[image]

The Dom references the reboot.scss and the root.scss here:

[image]

And this is my AppAsset:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{

    public $sourcePath = '@app/assets/app';
    public $baseUrl = '@app';

    public $css = [
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
        awesome.min.css',        
    ];

    public $js = [ 'js/scripts2.js',
                   'js/scripts_slider.js',
                   'js/scripts_gocardless.js'
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```

And this is the vendor BootstrapAsset under \vendor\yiisoft\yii2-bootstrap4\src

```
<?php

namespace yii\bootstrap4;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@npm/bootstrap/dist';
    public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.css',
    ];
}
```

If I change the AppAsset to:

```
'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'
```

...I get a positive result here:

[image]

with the insertion that you recommended I put it into vendor/bower-asset/bootstrap.css which is the older version of bootstrap and it worked after I rebooted my browser.

What would the equivalent command be for bootstrap4 to work under vendor/npm-asset's bootstrap.css?

Comment: You should not modify anything in the `vendor` folder because when you update composer dependencies all your changes will be lost. You should put your custom CSS in the stylesheet file that will be loaded with your app - create your own Asset in /frontend/assets and load css through it. Read https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets

Comment: Ok. I inserted .has-error .help-block { color: red; } into frontend/assets/app/css/site.css and included the path 'css/site.css' into the $public variable array of my AppAsset and working fine.

Comment: After reading https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/issues/151 I inserted **.has-danger** .help-block {color: red;} into frontend/assets/app/css/site.css, included the path 'css/site.css' into the $public variable array of my AppAsset and changed the $depends variable from 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' to 'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' and now I am getting the red error message as well for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for this is to verify its CSS and adjust it. Right-click the error message and choose `Inspect Element` (or `Inspect` or something similar, depending on the browser) from the menu. You should see the DOM tree with something like

```html
<p class="help-block help-block-error ">Error message</p>
```

This might be different depending on your code but in Yii 2 by default this is how the validation errors are inserted. Now just style the `help-block-error` class in your stylesheet like

```css
.help-block-error {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way, write this style in your css file, like "style.min.css" :

```
.help-block {
    color: red;
}
```

red or every color you want.